# Blackberry 10 Signing issue

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

Suddenly today morning when I signed my andriod app for Blackberry 10 in Eclipse the Signing was keep on happening but didnt stopped and I got .wrn,bar file I didnt get the lsv file and the signing also didnt complete.Was there any issue in Blackberry server even I checked out with many of my friend developers they also said me the same .Has anyone got such issue today and have solved kindly share on how to fix the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always check about the health of BB Signing Servers using this url -

http://isthesigningserverdown.com/

> Besides, if they have any maintenance work going on, there are notifications/messages on Blackberry Developer Support Forum

UPDATED 27-02-2014:

> This link seems broken since few days back.. Will re- edit when I will found any update regarding this.

UPDATED 28-02-2014 Its not supported from now -

> http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/What-about-isthesigningserverdown/td-p/2799877

Comment: http://isthesigningserverdown.com/ -- It seems to me it is broken URL it saying Oops! XYZ could not connect to isthesigningserverdown.com If it so, you should update the link here

Comment: hmm same here.. may be today its down.

Comment: It is still same, if you won't update your answer, I will flag it because link is broken, please update it

Comment: Rollback my downvote, but update it if it still after few days otherwise I will do same and flag it so

Comment: @Williams sure :). Besides, I have asked for the same on concerned forum - http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/What-about-isthesigningserverdown/td-p/2799877

Comment: @Williams It will be likely to be down for 6 months. Check above link.